# Tumblr embeds iframe within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, tumblr

I am trying to get some responsive videos working with Tumblr, using fitvid.js. However, Tumblr seems to be wrapping the YouTube embed twices, like so:

```
<div class="post video">
 <iframe src="tumblr.com/etc">
   <iframe src="youtube.com/etc"> // I cannot change the inline style, because it's wrapped
    This is the actual youtube embed!
  <iframe>
</iframe>
```

I'm not quite sure is wrong here. I've got the following code:

```
{block:Video}
<div class="post video">
        {Video-700}
</div>
{/block:Video}
```

Would anyone know why this is happening? Is there a way I can stop Tumblr wrapping them. Is this an error on my behalf? I've seen other videos on Tumblr that are not wrapped twice.

Comment: Can you share the embed code you are using, I would imagine that is the fault.

Comment: The embed code is generated by tumblr — I just enter the video URL and it does the rest with `{Video-700}`

Comment: Can you share the URL please?

Comment: Ah, I've discovered it's not the mark up, but how Tumblr process embedded urls when you submit them as a 'video', it wraps them in a safe tumblr iframe. I assume as a safety precaution? If I submit an embed as a text post, it works — very annoying

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm this. Seem Tumblr is changing how they handle video embeds. :(

Comment: I'm not sure of what's happening exactly, but try using `{VideoEmbed-700}` instead of `{Video-700}`

Comment: @bfred.it Neither effect how Tumblr generates the embed, they are theme related operators. I can confirm video embeds seem to be acting normal again.

Comment: That's incorrect, `{VideoEmbed-700}` just outputs the `<iframe>` while `{Video-700}` outputs a bunch of javascript and the iframe will be placed in a fixed-width `div` (but only for Tumblr videos, not YouTube's)